# Accuracy of Date.now() in browsers

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, utc

I've seen plenty of questions about how to get the date/time in JavaScript, and the answers always look something like

> `Date.now()` returns the UTC timestamp in milliseconds

But how reliable is that value really? Is it just based on the system clock of whatever computer is running the browser? If so, it seems like it could vary arbitrarily far from true UTC time, but how much variation should be expected?. I know caring about accurate milliseconds is a lost cause, but what about on the order of seconds or minutes?

Comment: Unless you're calling out to an external clock, all bets are off. Even then, it's sketchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it just based on the system clock of whatever computer is running the browser?

Right. It may well be completely inaccurate. For example, on my computer, whose clock is inaccurate, at this moment, `Date.now()` returns `1563724931361`, which, when passed into `new Date`, gives:

> Sun Jul 21 2019 11:02:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Which is completely wrong.

If the client wishes to present an inaccurate `Date.now()`, it's pretty trivial for them to do so, though *usually*, for most ordinary users, it'll be accurate, because *most* people have accurate clocks.

How accurate? It depends on the hardware, on how long it was since their computer last requested the time from a time server, and on how long since the computer was turned on (either from power off or standby/hibernate), but most times, it won't be off by more than a minute.

Answer (score 2):

There is always [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.now):

> **20.3.3.1 Date.now ( )**
>
> The **now** function returns a Number value that is the [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) 
>   designating the UTC date and time of the occurrence of the call to **now**.

That's it, there's no requirement for where the value comes from or its accuracy, so it's implementation dependent. In practice it seems that most implementations use values from the host system, so reliability is no better than what might be expected of a system clock and user provided settings such as calendar, timezone, DST, current time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of [side-channel memory attacks](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/ssca) the accuracy of the timing sources in a browser were limited. According to current information, from [W3C High Resolution Time issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/hr-time/issues/56#issuecomment-485583476), the limitation is a little different between different browsers:

- Mobile Chrome + Edge: 100us + 100us jitter
- Desktop Chrome: 5us
- Safari + Firefox: 1ms